# SQL query filled tempdb after 12.5 hours - optimization required

Tags: sql

I tried running this against a (rather large) database last night. It failed after 12.5 hours due to the tempDB file size.

I'm completely new to sql query optimization. Is there anything that stands out in this query from an optimization point of view? It runs smoothly in the dev environment, but again the size of the db is minimal in comparison.

```
SELECT 
     [Service].ServiceName AS [Service],
     PaymentMethod.[Description] AS PaymentMethod,
     Originator.OriginatorID,
     Originator.[Description] AS Originator,
     Count(*) AS Number,
     SUM(Amount) AS OrderAmount,
     SUM(AdminCharge) AS AdminCharge,
     SUM(TotalAmount) AS PaymentAmount

FROM Payment AS p 
   JOIN [Order] AS o
     on p.ServiceID = o.ServiceID
   JOIN PaymentMethod
     on PaymentMethod.PaymentMethodID = p.PaymentMethodID
   JOIN Originator
     on Originator.OriginatorID = p.OriginatorID
   JOIN [Service] 
     on [Service].ServiceID = p.ServiceID
   JOIN PaymentStatus AS ps
     on ps.PaymentStatusID = p.PaymentStatusID

WHERE
   ps.PaymentStatusID in (1,2,3)
AND
   PaymentTimeStamp BETWEEN '12/31/2012' AND '01/01/2014'
GROUP BY
   Originator.OriginatorID,
   Originator.[Description],
   [Service].ServiceName,
   PaymentMethod.[Description]
ORDER BY
   [Service].ServiceName
```

Comment: Any `index` on any of the columns?

Comment: 1 what is the database.
2 please provide us with query plan

Comment: If it worked how many rows would be returned before the group by and after? How big is temp db?

Comment: No index on any of the columns. The database holds payment information(log).

Comment: It worked in the developers copy of the database. It doesn't hold anywhere near as much data/records.

Comment: What's the data volume in these tables for prod also the selectivity. If there are no indexes in the tables then you can start with indexing the columns in the where and join conditions, and then share the stats.